# Laravel 8: Validate a blank JSON

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

I have this `[ ]` blank JSON and my problem in laravel validation are it sees it as a string. here is the code for my validation.

```
 $request->validate([
    'liquidationTable'=>'required',
    'file'=>'required',
  ]);
```

I saw a similar question to this but the answer is not working for me. please help me.

below is the sample data when it has data in it.

[image]

Comment: can you show how it looks if its has data

Comment: i uploaded some image sir,

Comment: try my answer if it works or not

Comment: it works, but when i add data it says array required
The liquidation table must be an array.

Comment: can you tell exact requirement on validation

Comment: i dont want the string ` [ ] ` to be accepted.  i want it it to validate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234193/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-paul-iverson-cortez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do using `array min`

```
 'liquidationTable'=>'required|array|min:1',
```

or using custom validation

```
$this->validate($request,[
          'liquidationTable'=>['required',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                  $liquidationTable=json_decode($value);

               if (json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE || count($liquidationTable)==0) {
                  $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
              }
          }],

      ],[
          'liquidationTable.required'=>'custom message',
        
      ]);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, it means a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending JSON but an array since "[]" would pass the required check.

You could use 'present' validation rule:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-present

> The field under validation must be present in the input data but can
> be empty.

```
 'liquidationTable' => 'present'
```

Additionaly you can validate JSON with this rule (if you were to send a JSON):
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-json